# iOS App Rejected because of Guideline 11.13

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Our App has just been rejected by Apple citing guideline 11.13: Your app includes an account registration feature, which is considered an access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app.

As per guideline 11.13, our understanding is that one is not able to use external mechanisms  for purchases or subscriptions to be used "**in the app**"? Please note however that all our PAID subscriptions options offer real world, non-digital services that's used "**outside of the app**" - the https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ also specifically states that IAP can not be used to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App (guideline 11.3). The "in-app digital services" that are offered is available as part of our FREE subscription and is not what the user pays for on the PAID subscriptions.

In summary:

- None of our PAID subscription services are used "in the app", in other words all the PAID
  services are non-digital and is used/provided outside of the app
- All our in-app digital services are FREE

Based on the rejection: If you offer a non-digital (real world) subscription - is the only option to subscribe for such a subscription via our website and does that mean the account registration feature and all links to the website on the app has to be removed?  This guideline https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf also states that IAP may not be used for a real world services such as Gym Membership, but mentions nothing about account registration limitations? Guideline 11.3 and 11.12/11.13 is very contradictory...

This really is a grey area that's has us confused....

Comment: Just curious, since all in-app services are free, why registration to non-digital services is even needed in the app?

Comment: No one but Apple will be able to cleanly resolve this, but it sounds like the reviewers are not clear on the external nature of the registration. My suggestion is to clearly explain in the reviewer notes (1) why registration happens in the app, (2) what the effect of registration **is** in the app (for example, is it used as an ID card?), (3) what (if any) functions of the app change between registration and not (which will indeed be thorny if there are any), and (4) re-submit with the expectation of appealing it based on the particulars of the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @JoeSmith, we require registration in order to notify your emergency contacts via SMS when you press an Emergency button (digital service). When you however subscribe to our paid service, a medically trained agent will respond by phoning you directly - providing the relevant support & a host of other real world services (non-digital).

Comment: Thanks @BradBrighton, in my latest response via Resolution center, I've clearly listed the difference between our digital & non-digital services, exactly what the user pays for (non-digital services) and that PAID services are all offered "outside of the app". I'm waiting for a response at the moment after which I'd be able to provide additional information with regards to the nature of the registration.

Comment: Sounds like you're covering all the reasonable angles. Good fortune with it.